# How to enable Google Keyboard?

Tags: applications, settings, keyboard

Following [this suggestion](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/64218/20449) I have disabled `Google Keyboard` application. My entire system has crashed and upon restart, I can't see that application in application list, so I could reenable it.

How to restore `Google Keyboard`, so it would start appear again in `Settings > Apps > All`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All disabled apps are listed on `Settings > Apps > Disabled`, where you can re-enable any of it.

If for some reasons or in certain situations, `Disabled` tab does not appear (like in my case) and restarting device does not help, then you can open menu in `Apps` (three dots in right top corner) and select `Reset app preferences`.

After confirming all your disabled apps  become enabled again.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.  Go to Apps and tap the three dots in the upper right corner and select "Show system".  There's the Gboard now.